# Unsuported clause in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Ok, every query or piece of code I am trying to run in neo4j is simply not going no matter what. Then, I just tried to run the sample codes they give us for start and.... they are not running either:

I typed `:play movie graph` and everything went fine, but the sample code:

```
CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie {title:'The Matrix', released:1999, tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'})
CREATE (Keanu:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves', born:1964})
CREATE (Carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss', born:1967})
CREATE (Laurence:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne', born:1961})
[... etc etc ... ]
CREATE (Hugo:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving', born:1960})
CREATE (LillyW:Person {name:'Lilly Wachowski', born:1967})
CREATE (LanaW:Person {name:'Lana Wachowski', born:1965})
CREATE
(Keanu)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Neo']}]->(TheMatrix),
(Carrie)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Trinity']}]->(TheMatrix),
(Laurence)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Morpheus']}]->(TheMatrix),
(Hugo)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Agent Smith']}]->(TheMatrix),
(LillyW)-[:DIRECTED]->(TheMatrix),


WITH TomH as a
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) RETURN a,m,d LIMIT 10;
```

Well, I just reproduced some part of the code - which is really big and not the real point here - from the neo4j itself. But it gives the error:

```
ERROR: Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed
The following unsupported clauses were used: CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, 
CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, CREATE, MATCH, WITH. 
The system database supports a restricted set of Cypher clauses. The supported clause 
structure for procedure calls is: CALL, YIELD, RETURN. YIELD and RETURN clauses are optional. 
The order of the clauses is fix and each can only occur once.
```

I am slo getting a similar error if I use other statements like `LOAD CSV` or `RETURN` and I have no idea why this is hapenning.

Someone?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the correct database has not been selected. I presume you use the Neo4j desktop app, if so make sure that your db name displayed as

[image: here]

Comment: Dear Nurzhan, can you please explain why you think there is a db selection problem? The clauses can run on any database.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your create script to your query script. Thus run below script first and also remove the comma at the end

```
CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie {title:'The Matrix', released:1999, tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'})
CREATE (Keanu:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves', born:1964})
CREATE (Carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss', born:1967})
CREATE (Laurence:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne', born:1961})
[... etc etc ... ]
```

Then run your query;

```
 MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d) WHERE a.name = 'TomH' RETURN a,m,d LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: It does not work. Even if I run only `CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie {title:'The Matrix', released:1999, tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'})` it is followed by this error: `Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed`: `The following unsupported clauses were used: CREATE. 
The system database supports a restricted set of Cypher clauses. The supported clause structure for procedure calls is: CALL, YIELD, RETURN. YIELD and RETURN clauses are optional. The order of the clauses is fix and each can only occur once.`